# Can't start Activity when pressing an element on GridView

Tags: android, gridview

i want to start an Activity when any Image from the GridView is clicked.
I maked this but i have an error on `getApplicationContext()` :

```
The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}
```

Code:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (position==0) {
                         Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), carburant.class);
                         startActivity(intent);

                    }
                }

              });
```

Comment: use activityname.this instead of getApplicationContext(), try it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of poor reference to Context. Try this instead,

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(imageView.getRootView().getContext(), carburant.class);
                     startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: unfortunately, i have this error: The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

Comment: Same scope problem. You're trying to call "startActivity" on View. You need to call it from Context. "imageView.getRootView().getContext().startActivity(intent)"

Answer (score 0):

You have a scope issue. View does not have a getApplicationContext() - you must access the parent activity's scope to get the app context.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyParentActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), carburant.class);
```

Comment: Always an error message: No enclosing instance of the type Main_menu is accessible in scope. Main_menu class is the one that it sets the GridView(its XML).