# How to make this UI with imagebuttons?

Tags: android, imagebutton

I want to create my main UI like this one:
http://lh3.ggpht.com/RYB2ckycDc_4rb2bmsDzqLLmYcj37xDOA7d7sR6XIVfwRb3a44_HqMqfb1vdmtxTEidenVY4C9RcTREl

Is it possible to make that with ImageButton ? The images must have the same resolution?
Thank you very much.

XML file, one line of imagebuttons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/acceuil"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<ImageButton

    android:id="@+id/consom" 

    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/consom_icon">
</ImageButton>
<ImageButton

    android:id="@+id/param" 

    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/consom_icon" >
 </ImageButton>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

here is what i have:
http://imageshack.us/f/856/imagebutton.png/

Comment: I can't see why it wouldn't be possible. What did you try so far, where do you get blocked ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the GridView, you can populate it with your set of icons that you have in hdpi, mdpi and ldpi in your res/ folder. When you populate the list, make sure you give the icons and ID so that you can determine which button was clicked to start the activity/intent that button is supposed to complete.

Android has a solid example on the gist of what I'm saying. http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

Example on how to handle the clicks with a switch statement:

```
    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(new MyGridViewAdapter(this));
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.drawable.my_button:
                startActivity(new Intent("com.awesome.Activity"));
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried to use GridView but don't know how to make a treatment(launch activity) when i tap on an image. This example shows you how to create a GridView only and not how to make some treatments on it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012961/cant-start-activity-when-pressing-an-element-on-gridview/7013037#7013037 this is a topic that i created.

Comment: That's a different problem. The example shows you exactly how to detect which item was clicked (it makes a Toast when an item is clicked). I've updated my post with an example of what you're looking for.

Comment: if i want to trigger the carburant.java class, the last line should be like this ? startActivity(new Intent(carburant.class));  ??? Because i have an error

Comment: What's the error? Do you have the activity you're trying to start declared in your manifest? Try using the new Intent("com.package.anotherpackage.MyActivity") to start your activity

Comment: I solved the problem with this lines: switch (position) {
             case 0:
              Intent i = new Intent(acceuil.this,carburant.class);
                 startActivity(i);

Comment: the GridView is an excellent solution, but what is the best images resolutions. I'm really stucking. Want to make 2 images in a row, and the images are always very small even if i increase the resolution. how to solve that please(can't create other topic)?

Comment: DPI and resolution on Android are too much to explain here, you'll have to read this article: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html - Essentially resolution is irrelevant, you can make the images any size you want, what matter is the consistency between the different DPI levels for xlarge to small screens.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a 'dashboard' type UI like this using ImageButtons in a TableLayout but I think you would have problems if you want part of the image to appear to be over the edge of the button. You might be better using ImageViews which have a button-type image with another image over it.

Check out the android UI design patterns where they discuss a twitter-like app design.

**Edit:**
Try something like the following TableLayout

```
<TableLayout>
 <TableRow>
  <ImageButton />
  <ImageButton />
 </TableRow>
 <TableRow>
  <ImageButton />
  <ImageButton />
 </TableRow> 
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: exactly. I'm using ImageButons but don't know how to adjust every imagebutton to take the left and the second to take the right and in the bottom to take the left...etc.... i maked an XML file. please see my first post

Comment: The gridview is working perfectly for now. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have u try like this,

< RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/acceuil"

android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   **android:orientation="vertical"**
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

< LinearLayout ....... **android:orientation="horizontal** ...........>

< ImageButton

```
android:id="@+id/consom" 
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/consom_icon">
```

< /ImageButton>

< ImageButton

```
android:id="@+id/param" 
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:src="@drawable/consom_icon" >
```

< /ImageButton>

< /LinearLayout>

< comment!--- for second row imageButtons>

< LinearLayout ....... **android:orientation="horizontal** ...........>

< ImageButton

```
android:id="@+id/consom" 
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/consom_icon">
```

< /ImageButton>

< ImageButton

```
android:id="@+id/param" 
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:src="@drawable/consom_icon" >
```

< /ImageButton>

< /LinearLayout>

< comment!--- Linear/Relative Layouts for more rows as needed...>

< /RelativeLayout>